# Managing hierarchical data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, nested-sets, hierarchical

I came across this article http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ but I didn't get the "Adding New Nodes" part.

It says I can do this to add a new node:

```
SELECT @myRight := rgt FROM nested_category
WHERE name = 'TELEVISIONS';

UPDATE nested_category SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myRight;
UPDATE nested_category SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myRight;

INSERT INTO nested_category(name, lft, rgt) VALUES('GAME CONSOLES', @myRight + 1, @myRight + 2);
```

1. At the runtime I'll know the parent not the sibling.
2. What if the node doesn't have siblings at all, how can I add it?
3. How can I add a new root node?

Comment: Instead of that structure , you should use *closure table* approach.

Comment: Because whatever you do, there will be errors eventualy. This method is good for relatively small amount of records, but for bigger sets or more transactions at a time you should use closure table.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't matter the siblings. u can add the new node by just having its parent_id.
it works like this :   add the node as the most left child of the parent, then update the lft and rgt of the nodes that their positions are right of the new node(all nodes of the tree). all nodes of the tree are being updated currectly now.

for adding a new root node, u should set its parent_id to NULL.

I hope thats be useful for u.